# UITableView will not update data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cloudkit

I have the below TableView displaying products and products on sale. When a product is on sale it will have an image next to it.
The issue is when the product is updated to sale, the CKSubscription notification comes through and is handled( everything arrives correctly in the ViewController.

The problem is that when the first notification comes through everything works fine, but after that updated items to sale do not display the sale image. Which leads me to believe that there is an issue with the reloading of the tableView.

I have also tried `tableView.reloadData()` in `.recordUpdated` but it doesn't update. delegate and dataSource have been set on the storyboard. What am I doing wrong??

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
 var array:[CKRecord] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     addNotificationObservers()
     getData()
}


@objc func getData() {
    self.array = []
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: “Product”, predicate: predicate)

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 5
    queryOperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
        self.array.append(record)
    }
    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
        if error != nil{
          print(error?.localizedDescription)

        }
        else{
            if cursor != nil {
                self.askAgain(cursor!)
            }
        }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    Database.share.publicDB.add(queryOperation)
}

func askAgain(_ cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor) {
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 5

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {
        record in
        self.array.append(record)
    }
    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
        if error != nil{
            (error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            if cursor != nil {
                self.askAgain(cursor!)
            }
        }
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    Database.share.publicDB.add(queryOperation)
}

  func addNotificationObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: CloudKitNotifications.NotificationReceived), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
        let notification = notification.object as! CKQueryNotification
        if let recordID = notification.recordID {
            switch notification.queryNotificationReason{
            case .recordCreated:
                Database.share.publicDB.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, error) in
                    if record != nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            self.array.insert(record!, at: 0)
                            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .top)
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                        }
                    }
                }

            case .recordDeleted:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.array = self.array.filter{ $0.recordID != recordID }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            case .recordUpdated:
                Database.share.publicDB.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { (record, error) in
                    if record != nil {

                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    //gets the old record
                                    let getOldRecord = self.array.filter{ $0.recordID == recordID }
                               // gets position of old record
                                    let positionofOldRecord = self.array.firstIndex(of: getOldRecord[0])
                        print("here is the position of old record \(positionofOldRecord)")
                             //gets the array without the old record
                                    self.array = self.array.filter{ $0.recordID != recordID }

                                    //now go to the position of the old one and replace it with the new one
                                    var newArray = self.array

                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: positionofOldRecord!, section: 0)
                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
                            self.array.insert(record!, at: positionofOldRecord!)
                            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                        }
                                           }
                 }

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as? TableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let item = array[indexPath.row]
    if item[“whatsTheNumber”] == 0 {
    cell.saleView.isHidden=true
    }
    cell.configureCell(brandBame: item[“Name”]!. productName: item[“ProductName”]!)

    return cell
}
}
```

edit:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var brandNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saleImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var saleView: UIView!

func configureCell(brandName: String, productName:String){
    self.brandNameLabel.text = brandName
    self.productNameLabel.text = productName
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Comment: What does cell.configureCell() do?

Comment: See edit, i have added the code for the `TableViewCell` class.

Comment: Where does saleImage get set?

Comment: i set it on storyboard.

Comment: I would expect an if-statement somewhere, either in configureCell or in the tableview.cellForItemAt method that maybe hides or shows saleImage depending on data you get from your server. Where is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to do something like this in the `cellForRowAt` func:

```
 cell.configureCell(brandBame: item[“Name”]!, productName: item[“ProductName”]!, isSaleItem: item[“Sale”]!)
```

Where `item[“Sale”]` would be a boolean flag

and in the `configureCell()` func:

```
func configureCell(brandName: String, productName:String, isSaleItem: Bool){
    self.brandNameLabel.text = brandName
    self.productNameLabel.text = productName
    self.saleImage.isHidden = !isSaleItem
}
```

Comment: simple but didnt think of that. exactly what i needed!many thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thanks for the feedback :: Happy Coding!